# Integer partitions without repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, diophantine-equations

What combination of numbers makes a specific sum?

The code below is not very effective, because it also gives answers in which a number is used more than once even though it was given in the list only once.

```
IntegerPartitions[45, {4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]
```

> {{10, 10, 10, 5}, {10, 10, 9, 6}, {10, 10, 8, 7}, {10, 9, 9, 7}, {10, 
>     9, 8, 8}, {9, 9, 9, 8}}

Notice that $10$ is given just once as a number in the last argument of `IntegerPartitions`, yet it appears three times in the first answer, and twice in the second; likewise with $9$.

So how can *Mathematica* be coded to return answers that have unique elements?

P.S I know `FrobeniusSolve` does not work as it only returns how many times numbers/(elements of answers) appear in a specific answer.

Comment: You can use `Select`, eg `Select[  IntegerPartitions[35, {4}, Range[0, 12]] , 
 Length@Union@# == 4 & ]`

Comment: @george2079 You can use plain `Apply@Greater` instead of `Length@Union@# == 4 &` for this filtering approach, but this works just because these results have a descending order.

Comment: @george2079 Even better and what I originally sought is `DuplicateFreeQ`.

Comment: Brute force one-liner `Select[Subsets[yourList,{subsetLength}],Total@#==sum&]` e.g. `Select[Subsets[Range[10],{4}],Total@#==25&]`

Comment: `IntegerPartitions[45, {4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]` gives `{}`. It pays to post correctly functioning code, else it is just confusing.

Comment: It so happens that this was the first question I ever asked on any Stack Exchange site.  [A variation of IntegerPartition?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5018252/618728)  @Daniel Lichtblau answered that one, too. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Could set this up as a 1-0 integer linear programming problem.

```
Module[{vars = Array[a, 10]}, 
 vars*Range[10] /. 
   Solve[Flatten@{vars.Range[10] == 28, Total[vars] == 4, 
      Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, vars]}, vars, Integers] /. 0 -> Nothing]

(* Out[98]= {{5, 6, 8, 9}, {5, 6, 7, 10}, {4, 7, 8, 9}, {4, 6, 8, 
  10}, {4, 5, 9, 10}, {3, 7, 8, 10}, {3, 6, 9, 10}, {2, 7, 9, 10}, {1,
   8, 9, 10}} *)
```

Comment: Somewhat more ghastly: `In[255]:= sum = Sum[a[j]*x^j, {j, 1, 10}];
Apply[List, 
   Coefficient[
    Nest[Expand[sum*#] /. {a[x_]^2 :> 0, x^j_ /; j > 28 :> 0} &, sum, 
     3], x^28]] /. ii_Integer*(x : Repeated[a[_], {4}]) :> {x} /. 
 a[j_] :> j

Out[256]= {{5, 6, 8, 9}, {4, 7, 8, 9}, {5, 6, 7, 10}, {4, 6, 8, 
  10}, {3, 7, 8, 10}, {4, 5, 9, 10}, {3, 6, 9, 10}, {2, 7, 9, 10}, {1,
   8, 9, 10}}`

Answer (score 3):

Finding sums of unique integers out of `alternatives`, with `count` of them picked, summing up to `sum`:

```
Function[{sum, count, alternatives}, 
  With[{vars = Array[v, count]}, 
   vars /. Solve[
     Total@vars == sum && Greater @@ vars && 
      And @@ Table[
        Or @@ Table[var == alt, {alt, alternatives}], {var, vars}], 
     vars]]][25, 4, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]

(* {{8, 7, 6, 4}, {9, 7, 5, 4}, {9, 7, 6, 3}, {9, 8, 5, 3}, {9, 8, 6, 2},
    {9, 8, 7, 1}, {10, 6, 5, 4}, {10, 7, 5, 3}, {10, 7, 6, 2}, {10, 8, 4, 3},
    {10, 8, 5, 2}, {10, 8, 6, 1}, {10, 9, 4, 2}, {10, 9, 5, 1}} *)
```

The approach here is to use variables `v[1]`, `v[2]`... (`count` in total) in `Solve` and constrain solutions in a following manner:

- variables sum up to `sum`,
- they are in decreasing order which implies non-equality, and
- each of them has value equal to one of alternatives listed.

This is not really particularly efficient implementation, but it does the job in smaller cases.

If you can limit the range of solutions to something like integers in a specific range, you can also simplify and speed up the problem considerably:

```
Function[{sum, count, min, max}, 
  With[{vars = Array[v, count]}, 
   vars /. Solve[
     Total@vars == sum && Greater @@ vars && 
      And @@ Table[min <= var <= max, {var, vars}], vars, 
     Integers]]][25, 4, 1, 10]
```

The result is the same.

It would also be possible to apply discrete `LinearProgramming` to the problem, but this would provide just one instance of a solution (likewise to `FindInstance` instead of `Solve`).